# I need to use a keyboard option like Control Alt s in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to use a keyboard option like <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> in Selenium Webdriver. can anybody help me out in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JAVA:

```
String saveIt = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "s");
driver.findElement(By.whatever("anything")).sendKeys(saveIt);
```

***UPDATED***
Thanks to Slanec to point out that the Keys.chord can accepts more than two keys.

Comment: Hello David, i want Ctrl+Alt+s Action has to be performed not ctrl+s alone!!!! got my question?? sorry if i where wrong anywhere

Comment: Sorry, I've missed that. Please have a look at this to see if it helps:http://test-mate.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/key-combinations-in-selenium-1-2.html

Comment: @Kameswaran Is it such a problem to look at the proposed method [`Keys.chord()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html#chord%28java.lang.CharSequence...%29) and discover that it takes any number of arguments and therefore can be easily adapted from the answer?

Comment: The `Actions` example is hilariously bad. Do `new Actions(driver).sendKeys(driver.findElement(By.id("name")), Keys.CONTROL, Keys.ALT, "s", Keys.NULL);`. The NULL at the end is required, as the `sendKeys()` method of `Actions` class is different from the `WebElement` one. It does not release the modifier keys.